# How to display from a linked list with a class as template type?

Tags: c++, linked-list

So I have the following class:

```
class Message
{
private:
    vector<string> messageLines;
    int numLines;
public: 
    void setNumLines(int nLines) {numLines = nLine;);//setting number of lines in the message
    bool setMessage(int lineNum, string message);//fills up the vector
    ostream& writeMessage(ostream &os)// overloding << operator, displays the vector.
}
bool Message :: setMessage(int lineNum, string message)
{
     if (lineNum > 0)
     {
         messageLines.push_back(message);
         return true;
     }
}
ostream& Message:: writeMessage(ostream &os)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < messageLines.size() ; i++)
    {
        os << messageLines[i] << endl;
    }
    return os;
}
```

From my main, after I declared a `LinkedList<Message> variable`  and a `Message messageVar` to fill up the vector, I inserted the  `Message` variable into a linked list like this:

```
variable.insert(messageVar);
```

Here is an example of what my main looks like:

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList<message> variable;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        Message messageVariable;
        messageVariable.setMessage(1, "random strings") 
        variable.insert(messageVariable) // filling up the list with 5 random strings
    }
}
```

However, when I try to call the linked list's display function and try to display the string values, i realized that the `cout << currPtr->getItem()` in the display function will not work since it I am displaying the `Message` type rather than a string. I know I should use the overloaded `<<` operator from the class I wrote but I have no idea where I should use it.

Here is the display function just in case:

```
template<class ItemType>
void LinkedList<ItemType>::display() const
{
    Node<ItemType>* currPtr = headPtr;//The Node<ITemType> is in another header file
    while (currPtr->getNext() != headPtr)                   
    {
        cout << currPtr->getItem() << endl; // cout can't display Message type
        currPtr = currPtr->getNext();       
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload `operator<<` in `Message`

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Message& rhs)
{
    return rhs.writeMessage(os);
}
```

Or, you can try a direct call to `writeMessage` in `display()`, such as:

```
currPtr->getItem().writeMessage(std::cout) << std::endl; // less elegant
```

---

PS:

```
ostream& writeMessage(ostream &os)// overloding << operator, displays the vector.
```

is not overloading `operator<<`, but it is just a helper function. You don't really need it here; it is a good idea to have such a function if you have a class hierarchy in which you mark it `virtual` and call it inside `operator<<`. This way, you have dynamic binding via a non-virtual (in this case non-member) function. This idiom is called NVI (non-virtual interface), and it is useful because it lets you define a mandatory implementation (in this case `operator<<`), which can call the "right" display function at run-time. So basically each derived class overrides `writeMessage`, but there is only one `operator<<` defined in the base class which "knows" to call the right `writeMessage`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But are there any other way besides adding a friend function or any other functions in the class?

Comment: You can just paste the code of `writeMessage` inside the `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Message& rhs)`. Your `writeMessage` is a helper function, and you don't really need it here, unless you may think about a class hierarchy, making it `virtual`, then calling it from `operator<<`. You need to make your `operator<<`  `friend` though, there is no other way, unless you don't access protected/private members, in which case `operator<<` can just be declared outside your class and use its public interface.

Comment: @CowEatsGrass see my updated edit, you can call directly `writeMessage` in the `display()` function, but it looks a bit messy.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help. I am going to give this one to you. Also, one quick question, when I try to do the cout<<currPtr->getItem().writeMessage(cout), the memory address of the list is also displayed. Any way to get rid of that?

Comment: you don't need the first `cout<<`. `currPtr->getItem().writeMessage(cout)` returns a stream, which is then converted into a pointer, which is then displayed by the first `cout`. It is almost like writing `cout << cout << endl`. So use just `currPtr->getItem().writeMessage(cout) << std::endl;`

Comment: Got it! Guess I still need more practice on these kind of stuff to get used to it...